# animation with delay android in ImageView

Tags: android, animation

I'm trying to implement animation with delay in android, but in my case the imageview is infinitely rotating, because i don't know how can i dynamically stop and start it.

```
final RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0f, 350f, 15f, 15f);
        anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        anim.setDuration(700);
        imageView.startAnimation(anim);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [setRepeatCount](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setRepeatCount(int)) arguments and [setStartOffset](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setStartOffset(long)) method. First one allows you to limit repeated animation, second one - introduce a time delay.